# HTML 5 Validator outputs error for span inside p

Tags: html, validation

I'm having a strange error:

[image]

The thing is that I've used spans inside divs before - in fact, [according to the W3C](http://goo.gl/Is1Ti), you can use span tags inside what's called "Phrasing Content" (the intra-paragraph level, which obviously the p element is all about), unless of course I'm misunderstanding something.

It doesn't break the website, but I'd like the document to validate.

The source code for the view (I'm using Codeigniter) can be found here: https://gist.github.com/1688702

That's the only error the W3C validator outputs.

Any thoughts? Perhaps a way to fix or circumvent this?

Comment: Please type out the error message and include the relevant parts of the code. It's not that hard surely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote spam instead of span on line 74.

Comment: Oooooh. Overlooked. That's what happens when you work with someone elses code on a really tight deadline. I was completely sure that is was something stupid. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Typo. It says `spam`, not `span`, in the error message.